# Tag merge request: [wordpress-plugin-dev] and [wordpress-plugin]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[wordpress-plugin-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin-dev) claims to be **"For issues related to wordpress plugin development"**, but as Stack Overflow is for issues related to development, and we already have the [wordpress-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin) to cover that -- what does this additional tag give?

Can [wordpress-plugin-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin-dev) (1,307) being merged into [wordpress-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin) (5,793)?

Comment: I would thread carefully here, as [wordpress-plugin] can give the impression that we accept questions *about plugins*, even if they are not programming related (ie, installing X plugin, or [specific issues with an specific plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501349/)).

Comment: [status-somewhat-completed], both of them were merged with [wordpress] by top users of those tags.

Answer (score 2):

As Braiam's comment implies, it would likely be better to reverse the synonym direction.